# How to uninstall Windows and install Ubuntu instead?

Tags: system-installation

I want to uninstall Windows and install Ubuntu on my laptop. For now I have `Windows 7 Professional` and the version of Ubuntu that I want is `Ubuntu 13.04`. My question is:

> What should I do to uninstall Windows 7 and install Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop?

Thanks.

Comment: I belive that you could achieve this by simply [installing ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Comment: also check: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail#.UhB6kq7yk38